# Can AngularJS $resource be tweaked to support JSON bodies on GET requests?

Tags: angularjs

I am using $resource to access an API which expects a json body with GET requests.

By default, angularjs serializes the data as queryparams but that is not what I need. Is there some configuration or hack to get the `$resource` to serialize data into a body instead of queryparams for a GET request?

Comment: Can you just use $http or maybe [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

Answer (score 1):

Although a [GET body is allowed by the HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), it's really not a good idea to use them. You'll get very poor interop with other systems (proxies for example, transparent or otherwise).

Not being able to set a body on $resource with GET is just one example of the sort of poor interop you're going to see.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a simple reason: The browser doesn't send a payload when `GET` is used. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-send-method) says the following about the `send` method of `XMLHttpRequest`:

> The optional argument provides the request entity body. The argument is ignored if request method is GET or HEAD.

So it's not an Angular issue or a limitation of `ngResource`. It's not possible at all in a standard compliant browser.